# How to create an event handler for a MenuItem on a ToolStripDropDownButton?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, events, .net-5, toolstrip

I'm using a ToolStrip control as a menu on a form. I have configured it with the Items Collection Editor. It seems that events cannot be configured in the Items Collection Editor. The ToolStrip itself has the `Click` and the `ItemClicked` events.

My menu contains a DropDownButton `Tools`. `Tools` contains a MenuItem `Config`. I need an event fired when I click `Config`.

The events `Click` and `ItemClicked` are just fired when I click `Tools` but not when I click the MenuItem `Config`.

I have not found any help on this simple task. Probably it's too simple to be discussed.

Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: What happens when you open the DropDownButton (at design-time) and _doubleclick_ the menu item? It _should_ generate the event handler for you. Alternatively, you could use a _single_ click, go to the Properties window, click on events (the ⚡ icon), and then select an event.

Comment: What do you mean with 'open the DropDownButton'? It doesn't react when I click it in the designer. I can only right-click the ToolStrip and select `Edit Items...`.

Comment: Maybe I have to mention that I'm using .NET 5.0.

Comment: Yeah, you should've mentioned that. I can see that it's a bit different in .NET 5.0. Well, the easiest solution would be to go to the Properties window, open the drop-down there, find and select your MenuItem (`Config`), click on events, and then find the event you want and double-click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the event handler using the designer, you may follow these steps:

1. Go to the Properties window (or press <kbd>F4</kbd>).
2. Open the drop-down that lists all the controls on your form and locate the `MenuItem`.
3. Click on "Events" (the ⚡ icon).
4. Find the event you need to use and double-click on it.

Here's a demo:

[image: Find the MenuItem control and generate an event handler]

Alternatively, you may create the event handler yourself using code. For example, add this line to your form constructor:

```
toolStripMenuItem1.Click += ToolStripMenuItem1_Click;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution.